# PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

```
Android Running app on sdk_gphone_x86
Sentry Logger [log]: Unhandled promise rejections will be caught by Sentry.
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: ReactNativeErrorHandlers
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Release
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: InboundFilters
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: FunctionToString
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Breadcrumbs
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: LinkedErrors
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Dedupe
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: HttpContext
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: EventOrigin
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: SdkInfo
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: DebugSymbolicator
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: RewriteFrames
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: ExpoManagedIntegration
device
false
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (C:\Users\hassn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (C:\Users\hassn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
    at read (C:\Users\hassn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\hassn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:135:5)  
    at call (D:\personal\teleMed-master\node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)
    at next (D:\personal\teleMed-master\node_modules\connect\index.js:183:5)
    at remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware (C:\Users\hassn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\src\middleware\remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware.ts:31:3)
    at call (D:\personal\teleMed-master\node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)
    at next (D:\personal\teleMed-master\node_modules\connect\index.js:183:5)
    at serveStatic (D:\personal\teleMed-master\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
```

I get this after expo start as soon as I run my app from iPhone. What is extra weird is that it's running code I've commented out, and is also running in some sort of infinite loop.

I'm unable to solve in react native can some one please help me out this issue [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlCsC.png)